# Show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\Vert x \Vert_{2}^{2}e^{-\alpha \Vert x \Vert_{2}^{2}}\operatorname{d}x = \frac{d}{d\alpha}(\pi/\alpha)^{n/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gaussian-integral

> Consider the integral
>   $$I_{n}(\alpha) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{-\alpha\Vert x \Vert_{2}^{2}}\operatorname{d} x,\quad \alpha>0,$$
>   onde $\Vert x \Vert_{2} = \sqrt{x_{1}^{2} + ... + x_{n}^{2}}$ denotes the euclidean norm of $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, e $\operatorname{d} x = \operatorname{d} x_{1}\operatorname{d} x_{2}...\operatorname{d} x_{n}$.
>
> (a) Show that $I_{2}(\alpha) = \pi/\alpha$ and conclude that $I_{1}(\alpha) = \sqrt{\pi/\alpha}$.
>
> (b) Show that $I_{n}(\alpha) = (\pi/\alpha)^{\frac{n}{2}}$.
>
> (c) Show that
>   $$\frac{d}{d\alpha}I_{n}(\alpha) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\Vert x \Vert_{2}^{2}e^{-\alpha \Vert x \Vert_{2}^{2}}\operatorname{d}x$$

**For (a).** Using polar coordinates, we have $x = (r\sin \theta, r \cos \theta)$ e então
$$I_{2}(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\lim_{\epsilon \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\epsilon}e^{-\alpha r^{2}}r \operatorname{d}r \operatorname{d}\theta = \pi/\alpha.$$
Thus,
$$I_{1}(\alpha) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\alpha x_{1}^{2}}\operatorname{d} x_{1} = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\alpha(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})}\operatorname{d} x_{1} \operatorname{d} x_{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}e^{-\alpha\Vert x \Vert_{2}^{2}}\operatorname{d} x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{I_{2}(\alpha)}.$$

---

**For (b).** I'm using induction but, I'm not sure about my proof. 
$$I_{n+1}(\alpha) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}e^{-\alpha\Vert x \Vert_{2}^{2}}\operatorname{d}x = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{-\alpha\Vert \tilde{x} \Vert}e^{-\alpha \Vert x_{n+1}\Vert_{2}^{2}}\operatorname{d}\tilde{x}\operatorname{d}x_{n+1} = I_{n}(\alpha)\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\alpha \Vert x_{n+1} \Vert_{2}^{2}}\operatorname{d}x_{n+1} = (\pi/\alpha)^{\frac{n}{2}}(\pi/\alpha)^{\frac{1}{2}} = (\pi/\alpha)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}.$$

---

**For (c).** I'm having trouble. I'm tried to write $\Vert x \Vert_{2}^{2} = u$, but I didn't get anything interesting.

---

Can someone help me?

Comment: For Part $(c)$, differentiate under the integral of $I_n(\alpha)$.

Comment: The derivative of $(\pi/\alpha)^{n/2}$ as a function of $\alpha$ is negative. How can it be equal to a positive integral:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (b) is fine. Alternatively, you can avoid induction by directly showing $I_n(\alpha) = (I_1(\alpha))^n$.

For (c), differentiate under the integral, and recall $\frac{d}{d\alpha} e^{c\alpha} = c e^{c \alpha}$. Also should the right-hand side be $- \int \|x\|^2 e^{-\alpha \|x\|^2}\, dx$?

Comment: Of course! Thank you!